# Jquery change the url of a button with a twig value

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, symfony

I have written some code to chance the href attribute of my button using Jquery, Twig, Laravel and Symfony. I have some problems with changing the current href into the result of the on chance method.

This is my code:

```
<div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
            <select id="select">
                {% for relation in relations %}
                    <option value="{{ relation.id }}">{{ relation.company }}</option>
                {%  endfor %}
            </select>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <a role="button" id="js-save-button"  data-method="POST" data-remote="true" data-disable-with="Saving..." href="{{ route('exportRelationFromPhonebook', [item.id]) }}" class="btn btn-primary">New Relation</a>
            <a role="button" id="edit-button" class="btn btn-primary" href="/phonebook/{{ item.getKey() }}/1">Existing relation</a>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-secondary" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
        </div>
    </div>
```

The `href` that I'm trying to chance is the one to belongs to the button with the id edit-button.

```
<script>
$(function(){
    $('#select').on('change', function(e)
    {
        $('#edit-button').attr("href", "/phonebook/{{ item.getKey() }}/"+$(this).val());
        console.log($('#edit-button').attr("href"));
    });
});</script>
```

When I use `console.log($('#edit-button').attr("href");` it returns the exact value that I want it to be.

Examples:

```
/phonebook/191/5
```

or

```
/phonebook/191/22
```

But for some reason, the url doesn't change. It is still `/phonebook/191/1`. What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: I'm not sure if you kan use the `{{ }}` in a javascript string.

Comment: Well, If i log the result it is exacly what I need. I just changed the href attrbute to be something like this: $('#edit-button').attr("href", "http://stackoverflow.com/") and that didnt do the job either, looks like it my button href atrribute won't chance at all.

Answer (score 1):

You should store the `{{ item.getKey() }}` in some other attribute for example `data-key`. After that only get the key to update the `href`.

for example 

`<a role="button" id="edit-button" class="btn btn-primary" data-key="{{ item.getKey() }}" href="/phonebook/{{ item.getKey() }}/1">Existing relation</a>`

in script

`var key = $('#edit-button').attr("data-key");
$('#edit-button').attr( "href", "/phonebook/"+key+"/"+$(this).val() );`

Comment: Could be better yes, but still the url doens't change.